# jquery slider with value above it which travels with the slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, uislider, jquery-ui-slider

I've made a slider with query/slider and styled it with css. ( http://jsfiddle.net/9qwmX/ )

I succeeded to put the selected value into a div container; but now I want the container to 'travel' with the slider accordingly. 
I've tried to use the `ui.handle` and its css `left` property which is a percentage. But the behavior is somewhat strange: sometimes it travels with the left side of the slider and sometimes with an offset of 10px.

Question: does anybody know a good way to let the box containing the slided-value travel with the handle?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Cw6u8/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just attach a tooltip-like div that you can append to the handle so it moves along with it. You just have to position it with CSS, like so:

**JS**

```
var initialValue = 2012; // initial slider value
var sliderTooltip = function(event, ui) {
    var curValue = ui.value || initialValue; // current value (when sliding) or initial value (at start)
    var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-inner">' + curValue + '</div><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div></div>';

    $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip); //attach tooltip to the slider handle
}

$("#slider").slider({
    value: initialValue,
    min: 1955,
    max: 2015,
    step: 1,
    create: sliderTooltip,
    slide: sliderTooltip
});
```

**CSS** <sup>tooltip borrowed from the twitter bootstrap framework</sup>

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1020;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-top: -2px;
    bottom:120%;
    margin-left: -2em;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-arrow {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9qwmX/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to build what you want, I am using `event.pageX`

```
var newLeft = 100;
$('#move').text(100).css('margin-left',115);
$("#slider").slider(
{
            value:100,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 50,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#slider-value" ).html( ui.value );
                var  pos = (event.pageX > newLeft)? event.pageX + 8 
                                                  : event.pageX - 42;
                newLeft = event.pageX;                
                $('#move').text(ui.value).css('margin-left',pos);
            }
}
);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/Cw6u8/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would have done it. To get you started:

Make use of the "handle" position:

```
var offset = $('.ui-slider-handle .ui-state-default .ui-corner-all"').offset();
var offsetLeft = offset.left;
var offestTop = offset.top;
```

Position your slide value box with absolute positioning:

```
#tijdlijnDatum { position: absolute; }
```

And do something with it in the `slide` event:

```
$( "#slider" ).slider({
   slide: function(event, ui) { 

       $('#tijdlijnDatum').css({ left: offsetLeft + 'px'  }); // etc
   }
});
```