# multiple sliders with value in tiptool?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I've seen a nice solution to a slider value on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11099757/jquery-slider-with-value-above-it-which-travels-with-the-slider)

The answer by Andres Ilich is a very nice solution here when there is one slider but what if I want to have multiple sliders on a page?

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevindoyleie/db8j4g0r/)

```
<div id='termslider'></div>
<div id='coverslider'></div>
```

with accompanying JavaScript and CSS

I've renamed the original tiptool classes in an attempt to differentiate the two sliders but so far without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the html relative to class selection, which is setting both tooltip slider handle:

```
$("#termslider").slider({
...
slide:
$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip)
...
create:
$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

});


$("#coverslider").slider({
...
slide:
$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip)
...
create:
$('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);

});
```

What you need is to set the slide handler of the related division, you can use jquery `find` function as follows:

```
$(this).find('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip);
```

Check the working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/db8j4g0r/5/